# How to find the number that is repeated in a line located in multiple files?

Tags: regex

I have this line in more then 1000 .php files. The number in every file is different, from 500 to 1000.

`$item_id = 752;`

In some files, some numbers are repeated and I don't know what are those numbers.

Can anyone give me a solution? A regex or a .php script, maybe..??

Comment: show your efforts. At least, show traversal of those 1000 files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a very simple and good answer. First open a text_editor, I am using GrepWin.

1. **Step 1:** Search this Regular Expression: `\$item_id = \d{3,4};` (This will show the results from every page)
2. **Step 2:** Select all results -> Right click -> "Copy filenames to clipboard" and "Copy text results"
3. **Step 3:** Open Excel. On the A columns, select cells and copy those filenames, and in the B column, select cells and copy text results (Only the numbers).
4. **Step 4:** From excel: DATA-> remove duplicates

Super Easy. Thank you jjspace for the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple regex search like this:
`\$item_id = \d{3,4};`
[Working Example](https://regex101.com/r/AhIQ19/2)

Note that this will match any lines that have numbers with 3 or 4 digits, if you specifically need the range 500-1000 that would work a little differently

Comment: a regex will be good jjspace, but your regex doesn't find any duplicate number.

Comment: To find duplicates I would first get all the matches and then check if any repeat. Also would they only repeat within a file or across multiple files?

Comment: in every file it exist only one instance of `$item_id = `. So the numbers repeats across multiple files, not within one file.